# Extract an exact value match in a file

Tags: php, regex

I have a file with below content:

> ServerName www.example.com ServerAlias example.com.com ServerAlias
>   www.example.com.k.net ServerAlias example.com.net ServerAdmin
>   "me.example.com" DocumentRoot "/web/docroot/0/example.com/htdocs"
>   AssignUserId user1example.com user1example.com Include
>   /www/vhost-include

I want to be able extract the exact match of `/web/docroot/0/example.com/htdocs` out of the file. It is easy using bash grep but - I am trying to do this in PHP. Also note that because of security reasons we do not allow bash execution from the PHP.

I have tried:

```
$loc = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
preg_match("\/web.*$", $loc, $f);
print_r($f); //nothing comes out
```

Comment: Enable `error_reporting` for once. Also `file()` and `preg_grep()` simulate the grep command more closely.

Comment: I did try `preg_grep` with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following works for me:

```
if (preg_match('#/web/[^"]+#', $repl, $arr))
   var_dump($arr[0]);
```

#### Live Demo: http://ideone.com/6Fagqe

Answer (score 1):

You can try this regex:

```
DocumentRoot\s*\"(.*?)\"
```

It will look for a url after `DocumentRoot` enclosed in `"`.

Comment: this does not deal with the user's actual problem, but it is a proper solution to what the user actually wants to do, so +1

Answer (score 1):

you simply forgot the regex separators surrounding the expression (ie. //)

```
preg_match("/\/web.*$/", $loc, $f);
```